# Cube rotation issue in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to detect the face(which face is infront of user) whenever I am rotating the cube.

Comment: Remember your rotation angles and test against their ranges. E.g. -45..45 would be front side. Also take into account that if you rotate cube upside down the sides along width will invert.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the scalar product (dot product) of each face normal with the +Z vector. The face for which the scalar product is maximal faces the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

datenwolf's answer has the right idea, but as written it isn't quite correct.  Let P denote the 3x3 upper triangular submatrix of the model-view-projection matrix you are using to draw the cube.  Then the third row of P (call it v for the sake argument) represents your view direction, unnormalized.  Now to check if a face is pointing toward the camera assuming outward pointing unit normals, you would simply check if the dot product of its normal with v is < 0 (not maximized).  This follows from the fact that:

```
 dot(a, b) = |a| |b| cos(theta)
```

Where the theta is the angle between them.  This can only be negative if they are pointing in opposite directions, which is the necessary and sufficient condition for a face to be pointing toward the camera, assuming it is physically positioned in front of the camera.